# Number of points of a polygon

Tags: list-manipulation

Hi I have the following polygon:

```
 a = {{{-105.5, 842.}, {-105.5, 496.464}, {1.4375, 519.379}, {28.5, 
  528.271}, {28.5, 655.25}, {3.6, 842.}}}
```

I want to count the number of points here. Here it is 6. Which could I write to find it. I used Length [a] but it gives me 1.

Thanks

Comment: You have one extra layer of {}. Length[First[a]] gives you 6

Answer (score 3):

You don't have a polygon. What you have is a list containing a list containing lists consisting of two numbers.
This is how you get a polygon from there:

```
a = {{{-105.5, 842.}, {-105.5, 496.464}, {1.4375, 519.379}, {28.5, 528.271}, 
      {28.5, 655.25}, {3.6, 842.}}};
polygon = a[[1]];
Graphics[{FaceForm[Green], Polygon@polygon}, Axes -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Posted as CW ...